# require 'lib/my_module' in deploy.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, capistrano

I have a module in in `lib/redmine.rb` that has some classes and stuff. I can call `Redmine.some_method` from the console just fine, but I'd like this module to be loaded during deployment using Capistrano.

I've tried:

```
require 'lib/redmine'
require 'redmine'
require './lib/redmine'
require '../lib/redmine'
load 'lib/redmine'
```

and all of those with a .rb at the end of it.

I can't seem to get access to the `Redmine` module from the deploy namespace...

Comment: is your module added to your git repository?  Does it exist on the target machine?

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be if you turn it into a gem project, and then simply refer to this
project via the name you gave it.

The problem I have with the code above is that I do not know the layout you use inside of redmine.rb and you are not showing the specific error.

Note that require() tries to go to the ruby SITE_DIR path first, so it would expect require 'redmine' to be installed like a gem  (or, via setup.rb which was the old way before gem was written).

Try this too for ad-hoc solution (but don't use it in production code; you modify the load path and this is not good nor needed; use the gem project layout and installation, it is much easier and safer in the long run):

```
$: << '.'
require './redmine.rb'
```